# Sqoop PSQLException "Sorry, too many clients already" on large exports

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I'm seeing Sqoop throw PSQLException "Sorry, too many clients already" when exporting *large* (200+ million rows) tables from HDFS to Postgres. I have a few smaller tables (~3 million) that seem to be working fine.

Even when the large tables fail it seems I still get ~2 million rows into my postgres table but I'm guessing that's just from the workers that didn't die since they got one of the connections first. My Postgres table is configured to allow 300 `max_connections` and there are about 70 connections always active from other applications so SQOOP should have ~230 to use.

I've tried toggling `--num-mappers` between 2-8 in my SQOOP export command but that hasn't seemed to make much of a difference. Looking at the failed hadoop job in the job tracker shows "Num tasks" as 3,660 in the map stage and "Failed/Killed Task Attempts" is showing 184/273, if that helps at all

Is there anyway to set a max # of connections to use? Anything else I can do here? Happy to provide additional info if it's needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your PostgreSQL-server say about the number of connections? SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;

Comment: @FrankHeikens it consistently returns between 70-78. These hadoop jobs are incredibly fast so i haven't been able to catch it when it's maxed out.

Comment: When using many database connections, you'd better use a connection pool like pgbouncer or pgpool. This also might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for my specific scenario. Thought I'd share my findings:

The core of the problem was the number of simultaneous map tasks running at a single time.

- The large tables had 280 map tasks running simultaneously (3,660
  total)
- List item the small tables had 180 map tasks running simultaneously (180
  total).

Due to this, the tasks were running out of connections since each of the 280 would try to spawn a connection and 280 + the existing 70 is > 300. So, I had two options: (1) jack up the postgres max_connection limit a bit, or (2) reduce the number of map tasks running at a single time.

I went with (1) since I control the database and jacked up `max_connections` to 400 and moved on with life.

FWIW, it looks like (2) is do-able with the following, but I couldn't test it since I don't control the HDFS cluster:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html

`mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job`